# 'python-software-properties' has no installation candidate while installing torch

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu and want to install Torch. I'm following [this guide](http://torch.ch/docs/getting-started.html).

The first line runs fine:

```
git clone https://github.com/torch/distro.git ~/torch --recursive
```

But fails on

```
cd ~/torch; bash install-deps;

Ign:1 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160420.1) xenial InRelease
Hit:2 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160420.1) xenial Release
Get:4 htt p://security.ubuntu. com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [94.5 kB]    
Hit:5 htt p://archive.ubuntu. com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                        
Get:6 htt p://archive.ubuntu. com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [94.5 kB]      
Fetched 189 kB in 0s (355 kB/s)                                      
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package python-software-properties is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  software-properties-common

E: Package 'python-software-properties' has no installation candidate

(Had to add spaces to the links because I don't have enough rep)

**dpkg -L python-software-properties | xargs ls -d > /dev/null** yields

dpkg-query: package 'python-software-properties' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
```

This command gives the same error message:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-software-properties
```

I ran `sudo apt-get install software-properties-common` and it installed fine, but I still get the same error.

I'm running the latest version of Ubuntu off a USB, 64-bit

Comment: That guide has a lot of command blocks; can you please identify (i.e., quote) the "first line" and the "second line" that you refer to?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 2):

Issue is in script `install-deps`

Please replace line 139 with following command.

```
sudo apt-get install -y software-properties-common
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Goto

```
Home -> Torch -> Open install-deps
```

find the keyword **python-software-properties** and replace it with **software-python-common**, save and exit.

2.install the software-python-common with the command

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

3.run the command

```
cd ~/torch; bash install-deps;
```

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt install --reinstall python3-debian python3-chardet`

Will work just fine ;)

Comment: It may work just fine, but could you explain how it fixes the problem in the question?